# Drop a View or Table, unknowing which it is, in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am in a situation where I want to drop a view or table, but can only know at run-time which it is (same identifier though). This does not work:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS my_table_or_view;
```

Because if my_table_or_view is a table, it will throw:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: use DROP TABLE to delete table my_table_or_view
```

Likewise, I cannot use DROP TABLE, because it tells me to use DROP VIEW if i have a view at hand. I could catch the error, of course, but since this is part of a larger transaction, I would definitely prefer an answer that works using pure SQL (as understood by sqlite3). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about items in your sqlite database by SELECTing from a pseudo-table called sqlite_master.

In this case, you would do:

```
 SELECT type FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'my_table_or_view'
```

and the resulting information will tell you whether you're dealing with a table or a view.

More info: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7

Comment: So, how can I use this to drop what I have using **SQL only**? I cannot inline the result of your proposed query into my drop query, can I?

Comment: If you have someplace to catch the error, can you not simply emit the appropriate statement (`DROP TABLE` or `DROP VIEW`) from your code based the what you get from querying `sqlite_master`?

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But as I stated in my question, I would rather go SQL-only and was wondering if it is possible.

Comment: If you mean from a pre-written SQL script that is not being emitted under program control, I can't think of a way to do it.